# Why can't I open projects with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgs

I have a problem with QGIS that I've had both with version 2.2 and now with 2.8. I can't open the projects that I have saved. It is a project of 4 layers: a vector with a region of Madagascar, a river layer, a layer joined to the first one and a layer with GPS points.

When I open the project, go out a window with four columns: Layer Name, Type, Provider, Datasource. I click OK and get this message: "There are still 4 unhandled layer(s), that will be lost if you close now."

So I can't open my project.

Does anyone know what the problem is? What should I do?

I have a Mac Osx 10.9.5, 64 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably changed the location of the project file or the data files. The message means that QGIS cannot locate the data files at the location it expects them to be. You can double-click on the paths to open a file dialog which allows you to manually search for the files in your file system.

If this issue was caused by transferring a project, it might be helpful to check [Is there an automatic function in QGIS to package all files in a project for transferability?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/is-there-an-automatic-function-in-qgis-to-package-all-shapefiles-in-a-project-fo)