# Storing different shapefiles as "one" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, spatial-database

I converted OSM data to SpatialLite with ogr2ogr and loaded the resulting files (multipolygons, lines, multilinestrings, points) in QGIS (2.18). I added a river-polygon; then I styled the layers. 
[image]

Now I'd like to share the results with my collegues.

Is there a way of storing these layers and their styles in one single file?

Alternatively, what would be the most appropriate format to share my results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can revert back to Spatialite databases. Use the extension "QSpatialite" to create an empty DB (use the creation button, circled on the capture below), and add your layers to it.
[image: QSpatialite interface]

To add a layer, click on "Import QGIS Layers" button (the one with the QGIS icon).

You can now give your colleagues your `.sqlite` unique file, and they can import the layers through `Layers > Add Layer > Add Spatialite layer` menu item, or open it with QSpatialite, right-click on the layer they want in the table list and select `Load in QGIS`.

Hope this helps !

Jerry

Answer (score 5):

By definition, a shapefile can store one specific type of geometry. So it would not be possible to store layers of different geometry in one shapefile.

One way to share the data would be to share the individual shapefiles.

An alternative method is described on the following link to package and share data with QGIS -
[Is there an automatic function in QGIS to package all files in a project for transferability?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/is-there-an-automatic-function-in-qgis-to-package-all-files-in-a-project-for-tra)