# QGIS Project Packager

Tags: qgis

Is there a function in QGIS similar to the '[Workspace Packager](http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000Cr3iCAC&popup=false&lang=en_US)' in MapInfo that allows me to save a project and all the applicable layers together in a folder. I need to send a QGIS project to a client and I'm wondering if there's an automated way of gathering all the necessary files together.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Is there an automatic function in QGIS to package all files in a project for transferability?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/is-there-an-automatic-function-in-qgis-to-package-all-files-in-a-project-for-tra)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly I missed this post in my searches:

This post answers the question ->
[Is there an automatic function in QGIS to package all files in a project for transferability?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/is-there-an-automatic-function-in-qgis-to-package-all-files-in-a-project-for-tra)

You can use the [QConsolidate](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/) plugin.